# ERROR in src/app/app.module.ts(26,8): error TS1005: ')' expected

Tags: angular

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { SigninComponent } from './app/signin/signin.component';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

import {
    SocialLoginModule,
    AuthServiceConfig,
    GoogleLoginProvider,
    FacebookLoginProvider,
} from "angular5-social-login";

 
export function getAuthServiceConfigs() {
  let config = new AuthServiceConfig(
      [
        {
          id: FacebookLoginProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
          provider: new FacebookLoginProvider("*******")
        },
        {
          id: GoogleLoginProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
          provider: new GoogleLoginProvider("Your-Google-Client-Id")
        },
      ];
  );
  return config;
}
 
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    AppComponent,
    SocialLoginModule,
    BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [    
    {
      provide: AuthServiceConfig,
      useFactory: getAuthServiceConfigs
    }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  declarations: [SigninComponent]
})
 export class AppModule { }
```

estoy intentando conectar el login de facebook con la libreria angular5-social-login, pero me encuentro con el error ERROR in src/app/app.module.ts(26,8): error TS1005: ')' expected.

Dejo el fragmento de codigo

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! revisa esos enlaces.. cual es la linea 26?

Comment: Hola, gracias por las recomendaciones. La linea 26 es justo donde cierra ]; del metodo  getAuthServiceConfigs()

Comment: Creo que es por la coma del último elemento:
},]; <-- quitar coma a ver.